# Can not delete Core Data Entity regardless of Delete Rule

Tags: core-data, ios5

I am trying to delete a Core Data Entity and no matter what delete rule I use, it just won't work. It does not do anything at all.

I am using Firefox's Sqlite Add-on to browse the core data database and I can see all the rows there after the delete code runs.

My code for deletion looks like this

```
+(void)deleteCustomerWithID:(int)customerid inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext  *)context
{
Customer *customer = nil;

NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Customer"];
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id = %d", customerid];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"organization" ascending:YES];
request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *customers = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

if (!customers || ([customers count] > 1)) {
    // handle error
} else if (![customers count]) {
    // customer not found
} else {
    customer = [customers lastObject];
    [context deleteObject:customer];

    NSError *error; 
    if(![context save:&error]){
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error series %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
}
}
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any chance it's going through one of the other if/else branches?  Does `Customer` have any relationships with a "deny" delete rule defined?  (I see you said "no matter what delete rule" but have you checked all relationships?)

Comment: no Deny rules on any Entity at all..

Comment: Are you 100% sure the if branch with `deleteObject:` method call is executed and there are no saving errors? Delete rules should not play any role here as you're deleting object manually.

Comment: yes 100% sure - I checked by having a breakpoint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what went wrong but I ended up deleting all the relationships in Entities and then re-creating them. That seems to have solved the issue. I can now successfully Cascade Delete.